# combine ROS with Home Automation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written a ROS python package which provides a bridge to the OpenHAB home automation system (open source license)

OpenHAB is an open source system that connects to virtually any intelligent device, such as smoke detectors, motion detectors, temperature sensors, security systems, TV/audio, fingerprint scanners, lighting, 1-Wire, Wemo, CUPS, DMX, KNX, openpaths, Bluetooth, MQTT, Z-Wave, telephony, Insteon, weather sensors, and web services such as Twitter, etc. ROS also provides a basic Web GUI and Iphone/Android app for setting and dynamically viewing values. openhab.org/features

**Give your robot knowledge of the wider world**

**Use Cases:**

- A motion detector in OpenHAB triggers
  and ROS dispatches the robot to the
  location.
- ROS facial recognition recognizes a
  face at the door and OpenHAB unlocks
  the door.
- A Washing Machine indicates    to
  OpenHAB that the load is complete
  and ROS dispatches a robot to move
  the laundry to the dryer.
- OpenHAB MQTT binding indicates that
  Sarah will be home soon and a sensor
  indicates that the temperature is
  hot. ROS dispatches the robot to
  bring Sarah's favorite beer. OpenHAB
  turns on her favorite rock music and
  lowers the house temperature.
- A user clicks on the OpenHAB GUI on
  an IPAD and selects a new room
  location for the robot. The message
  is forwarded by the openhab_bridge to
  ROS and ROS dispatches the robot.

With the openhab_bridge, virtually any home automation device can be easily setup to publish updates to the openhab_updates topic in ROS, giving a ROS robot knowledge of any Home Automation device. ROS can publish to the openhab_set topic (or openhab_command) and the device in OpenHAB will be set to the new value (or act on the specified command).

To download and for more information:

https://github.com/answer17/openhab_bridge

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204891/combine-ros-with-home-automation/) by [corb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20674/corb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2015-03-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-03-13**:
Well, usually people post questions to the ROS users mailing list, which is reserved for announcements. In this case you do it the other way round. You post an announcement on ROS answers, which is reserved for questions. Please post this on ROS users. BTW: We already tested your package. Good job!

**Comment by [Johan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21880/johan/) on 2015-03-19**:
How can I connect my robot with the openhab_bridge?

**Comment by [Johan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21880/johan/) on 2015-03-19**:
Thanks for your reply. But how does the openhab bridge recognize the robot ?

My robot ist based on Arduino and has ROS

usually i used the following code for building a "connection" to be able to communicate.

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0
```

**Comment by [corb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20674/corb/) on 2015-03-19**:
Without Arduino/rosserial, it would run like this:

The linux system running ROSCORE would also launch openhab_bridge.  The Openhab bridge subscribes and publishes ROS topics.  The openhab bridge uses HTTP to talk to the Openhab REST interface.

**Comment by [Johan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21880/johan/) on 2015-03-19**:
Is it right that using Arduino/ rosserial is not able right now to connect with the openhab_bridge?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-12-17**:
@Johan please open a new question, instead of asking in comment section (you won't get sufficient attention by right persons in comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

there is an overview here:  http://wiki.ros.org/openhab_bridge.  The openhab bridge is a small ROS python package that you launch.  Your ROS robot would talk to OpenHAB by using ROS publish/subscribe to the bridge.

---

Originally posted by [corb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20674/corb/) with karma: 339 on 2015-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1